# GIT Workflow Question: Fetch, pull, clone... or just copy paste? (2 scenarios)

Tags: python, git, github

I'm trying to learn git and implement it into my routine more (as a solo, non-professional programmer). I have two workflow scenarios I'd love to get some clarity on.

**Scenario 1:**

Start new project. New directory. New virtual env. New git repo.

I want to import a module that I have previously uploaded to github in a different repo.
Let's say, a module with some helper functions for working with google sheets. We'll call it "helper.py"

My understanding of git pull is that it is to basically to sync up a local branch with the corresponding remote one. That's not really what I'm doing here as these are two totally different repos, two totally different branches... right?

I'm really just trying to get a "copy" of the latest version of the module into this new project. Is it fetch? Or just straight copy paste?

What is the correct way to do this?

**Scenario 2:**

After I properly integrate the "helper" module into my new local project, I notice a few ways to improve it.

I make these improvements locally, in this NEW project. In this NEW repo. Now I want to push the improved helper.py module to the remote helper repo.

However, I don't want to mess up the helper repo with version history of this new, unrelated project. What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: If I understand your goals correctly, have a look at [Git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this looks like exactly what I am asking about.

I realize the more simple ask is: how do you correctly implement a library that is NOT a part of pypi. Thus, would not be stored in the virtual env. Looks like submodule is the way regardless. Appreciate your help.